# Not Reading Millisecond Time Correctly

Tags: java, api-design

So I am pulling data from the OpenWeatherMap api and everying was going fine until I got to returning the sunrise and sunset times for Omaha, Nebraska. Ive looked at previous posts on here and used those as reference such as one using the TimeUnit class which is still off in my case and ones using Date/SimlpeDateFormatter but it seems they are outputting nearly the same time. The method to convert these times may look right to me but the times they convert to are not so. Is there a certain method I should use to convert them or am i doing something wrong with the current method I am using?

Methods that intake the time in milliseconds

```
public String getSunrise() {
    valueString = main.substring(main.indexOf("\"sunrise\"") + 10, main.indexOf("\"sunrise\"") + 20);
    System.out.println(valueString);
    Long rise = Long.parseLong(valueString);

    Date d = new Date(rise);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CDT"));
    String t = format.format(d);

    return t;
}

public String getSunset() {
    valueString = main.substring(main.indexOf("\"sunset\"") + 9, main.indexOf("\"sunset\"") + 19);
    System.out.println(valueString);
    Long set = Long.parseLong(valueString);

    Date d = new Date(set);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CDT"));
    String t = format.format(d);

    return t;
}
```

Console output of the methods

```
1588504675
Sunrise: 9:15 AM
1588555387
Sunset: 9:15 AM
```

From the current data it is pulling, the time should be sunrise = 6:17am and sunset = 8:23pm taken from this link: https://openweathermap.org/city/5074472. `main` is the full JSON string.

Comment: You should not be using `java.util.Date`. It's long list of problems are well-documented. Use the `java.time` package

Comment: You've println'd the valueString, but what is the actual long value resolving to? Print that out. Obviously, the same value is arriving at the Date() constructor in either case, regardless of what your string indicates. I'm curious what that long going into the Date constructor actually is, since it's identical each time, and not what the string seemed to indicate before you parsed it..

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a json decoder library for this?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I probably should actually. I looked at Jsonb but I'm still new to installing Maven dependencies and I'm not completely sure how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Methods that intake the time in milliseconds*: The value in the Open Weather Map API is in seconds, not milliseconds. In your question, `1588504675` is in the year 1970. But `1588504675000` is May 3rd 2020 (and the time portion is UTC).

Comment: Oh gosh that is embarrassing. Thank you!